# Is there any way to show a field on a listing page in Wagtail admin?

Tags: django, admin, customization, wagtail, modeladmin

I know that I can register my model as a Django model and add an image there but I need to save a pages' tree and identify my pages by an image on a listing page. To make a long story short, I need to show images on the listing page in admin.

[image: wagtail admin listing index page customization]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Create a template in `templates/wagtailadmin/pages/listing/_page_title_explore.html`

```
{% load i18n wagtailadmin_tags %}

{# The title field for a page in the page listing, when in 'explore' mode #}

<div class="title-wrapper">
    {% if page.sites_rooted_here.exists %}
        {% if perms.wagtailcore.add_site or perms.wagtailcore.change_site or perms.wagtailcore.delete_site %}
            <a href="{% url 'wagtailsites:index' %}" class="icon icon-site" title="{% trans 'Sites menu' %}"></a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if page_perms.can_edit %}
        <a href="{% url 'wagtailadmin_pages:edit' page.id %}" title="{% trans 'Edit this page' %}">{{ page.get_admin_display_title }}</a>
    {% else %}
        {{ page.get_admin_display_title }}
    {% endif %}

    {% block pages_listing_title_extra %}
        {% if page.youtube_video_id %}
            <img src='https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{{page.youtube_video_id}}/mqdefault.jpg' width='150'/>
        {% endif %}
    {% endblock pages_listing_title_extra %}

    {% include "wagtailadmin/pages/listing/_privacy_indicator.html" with page=page %}
    {% include "wagtailadmin/pages/listing/_locked_indicator.html" with page=page %}
</div>

<ul class="actions">
    {% page_listing_buttons page page_perms %}
</ul>
```

Pay attention on `{% block pages_listing_title_extra %}`, for example, you can add your variable from a model to this block.

Keep in mind that the admin template has been overwritten, and after upgrading the Wagtail core you may not see some new features.

Comment: Link to current HTML template: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/main/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/pages/listing/_page_title_explore.html

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add image, you don't need to override entire page title explore template. You can use just `pages_listing_title_extra` block.
Create file `templates/wagtailadmin/pages/listing/_page_title_explore.html` with content:

```
{% extends "wagtailadmin/pages/listing/_page_title_explore.html" %}
{% load wagtailimages_tags %}

{% block pages_listing_title_extra %}
    {% image page.image fill-100x200 %}
{% endblock pages_listing_title_extra %}
```

This should not break with new version of Wagtail (only if this template block would be removed/renamed).