# Is there a way to show images in a Wagtail Model Admin Record Listing page?

Tags: wagtail

I have reviewed the question on [Is there any way to show a field on a listing page in Wagtail admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60659310/is-there-any-way-to-show-a-field-on-a-listing-page-in-wagtail-admin) but my situation seems to similar but also different enough that that particular solution won't work for me.  Instead of on the Page listing I wish to achieve a similar thing on the Model Admin listing and I would think this should be such a common requirement that I am picking that someone must have done this before I have attempted it.

I haven't really figured out how to even try anything to get started but what I have looked at is the modeladmin template tags under wagtail.contrib.modeladmin on GitHub but I am completely guessing.

Can anyone point me to which templates I need to modify and whether I need to modify any of the template tags and how to override anything I need to override?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to override templates for this - this is standard functionality in ModelAdmin. Adding extra fields to the listing is done by setting `list_display` on the ModelAdmin class:

```
class BookAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Book
    list_display = ('title', 'author')
```

For displaying images, ModelAdmin provides [`ThumbnailMixin`](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/indexview.html#wagtail-contrib-modeladmin-mixins-thumbnailmixin):

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.mixins import ThumbnailMixin
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import ModelAdmin

class BookAdmin(ThumbnailMixin, ModelAdmin):
    model = Book
    thumb_image_field_name = 'cover_image'
    list_display = ('title', 'author', 'admin_thumb')
```

(`'admin_thumb'` is a special-purpose field name provided by ThumbnailMixin, and should be used rather than the actual image field on your model - `cover_image` in this example.)